# android alpha overridePendingTransition does not work unless rotation is also used

Tags: android, android-animation, fade, alpha, transition

I am having trouble getting  transitions to work by themselves. Alpha works if another transition is going on at the same time, but by itself.
The following fades in and out *(but not if "fromDegrees" and "toDegrees" are both equal to 0, which is essentially like leaving the <rotation> tag out)*:

**fadein.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="5000" >
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" />
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="1" android:toDegrees="0" />
</set>
```

**fadeout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="5000" >
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" />
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="1" android:toDegrees="0" />
</set>
```

But these do not work:

**fadein.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="5000" >
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" />
    <!-- <rotate android:fromDegrees="1" android:toDegrees="0" /> -->
</set>
```

**fadeout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="5000" >
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" />
    <!-- <rotate android:fromDegrees="1" android:toDegrees="0" /> -->
</set>
```

In fact, if I don't use rotation in this example, then the **5000** duration does not last 5 seconds but 0 seconds.

**New Information:**
Apparently, fadeout.xml can have the rotate tag omitted but fadein.xml still needs it.

**Clarification:**
If fadein.xml does not have rotation, then fadein and fadeout both don't work. If fadein does have rotation fadein and fadeout both **do** work.

**New Information:** If I do not use set, but use alpha directly it still does not work... I have to have rotation and alpha together in a set.

Comment: I had a similar problem and I would suggest you to make some trials with android:fillAfter,
android:fillBefore and android:fillEnabled. Afaik there was some bugs with sets as well.

Comment: I've tried all four combinations with fadein.xml but not with fadeout.xml yet... it still does not work.

Comment: typo at dec'c'elerate_interpolator ?

Comment: I'm not sure how that got there, it's not in the code, I'll fix it here.